# python function returns multiple dicts instead of one

Tags: python

Why does this recursive function keep returning multiple dictionaries instead of just one.

```
def retFiles(dir):
    data = {}
    root = set()
    os.chdir(dir)
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    for i in os.listdir(cwd):
        if os.path.isfile(i):
            data.setdefault(i, set())
            root.add(os.path.relpath(dir).replace("\\", "/"))
            data[i] = root
        else:
            preisci(i)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Uh... that function doesn't return *ANYTHING*...

Comment: Is the last line (print(data)) supposed to represent what **would** typically be returned from the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it makes sense why the method would return a list of lists (if the print(data) line is actually supposed to be the return).

```
    if os.path.isfile(i):
        data.setdefault(i, set())
        root.add(os.path.relpath(dir).replace("\\", "/"))
        data[i] = root
    else:
        preisci(i)
```

The line

```
data[i] = root
```

is assigning a list of paths to the i'th index of data. So if we are supposed to be returning data then data will contain multiple lists of paths.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

1. Your function isn't recursive (unless `preisci` calls `retFiles`, but you haven't shown that code).
2. It doesn't return *anything*, let alone multiple dictionaries as you claim.

I wouldn't actually use recursion here. Instead consider using the [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) function that can recursively walk down a directory and all its subdirectories.

To fix the second point, try changing the `print` to a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have the print in every function call.  So it will print every time this function is run, which is multiple times if the function runs itself recursively.  And yes, this function isn't recursive, but my guess is that you intended to type something like

```
else:
        retFiles(i)
```

in your implementation.  That still wouldn't work the way you likely want it to, but that would be the recursion I think you might be referring to.  And then you'd have multiple prints happen.